# Calculate monthly Modis NDVI of multiple regions using GEE Python API and export the results to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, google-earth-engine-python-api, reduceregion

This is more or less the second part of [Calculate monthly Modis NDVI using GEE Python API applied to one or multiple regions and export the results to a Pandas DataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429958).

I have a list of point coordinates. I want to obtain a monthly-year time series of the NDVI inside different buffer sizes around each one of this points.

With the answer I got to the previous question I could solve the problem for **one** region/polygon. It was very efficient and solved the problem in one step. But I wasn't able to adapt the code to make it run for several polygons. So I came back to my previous approach, similar to the JavaScript code I pasted in the previous question.

Trying to adapt it to Python this is what I could do:

```py
import pandas as pd  
import ee
ee.Initialize()
      
# I import this data from a .csv file, but to make a running exmample, here I create the DataFrame manually
data = [['Site-1', -42.44, 145.73],
        ['Site-2', -42.48, 146.36],
        ['Site-3', -42.14, 146.04]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Lat', 'Lon'])
 
# Convert the dataframe to FeatureCollection
features = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    g = ee.Geometry.Point([row["Lon"], row["Lat"]])
    feature = ee.Feature(g, {"Name": ee.String((row["Name"]))})
    features.append(feature)
pts = ee.FeatureCollection(features)

# Create different buffer sizes around each point
def makeBuffer(size):
    def addBuffer(feature):
        return feature.buffer(size)
    return addBuffer
pts1000 = pts.map(makeBuffer(1000))
pts5000 = pts.map(makeBuffer(5000))
pts10000 = pts.map(makeBuffer(10000))


#### Extract the mean NDVI for each Buffer ####
startDate = '2001-02-01'
endDate = '2003-03-31'

modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09GA_006_NDVI').select('NDVI').filterDate(startDate, endDate)


# Reducing across year-month
def calcNDVI(n):
    date = ee.Date(startDate).advance(n,'month')
    m = date.get("month")
    y = date.get("year")
    tempNDVI = (modisNDVI.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                .mean()
                .set('year',y)
                .set('month',m))
    return tempNDVI            

# calculate the number of months to iterate
StartD = ee.Date(startDate)
EndD = ee.Date(endDate)
num_months = ((EndD.get("year").getInfo() - StartD.get("year").getInfo()) * 12 +
              (EndD.get("month").getInfo() - StartD.get("month").getInfo()))

# iterate
modis_YrMo = ee.List.sequence(0, num_months).map(calcNDVI)


### Calculate the mean NDVI inside each polygon(buffer)
def calcmean(fc):
    def regionmean(image):
      reduced = image.reduceRegions(
                  collection = fc,
                  reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  scale = 30)
      return reduced
    return regionmean

finalNDVI_1000 = modis_YrMo.map(calcmean(pts1000))
finalNDVI_5000 = modis_YrMo.map(calcmean(pts1000))
finalNDVI_10000 = modis_YrMo.map(calcmean(pts1000))

print(modis_YrMo.getInfo()[1])
```

I think the problem is that my `calcNDVI()` function is not returning an `ImageCollection` but a `List` of objects that "apparently" are images.

For example, after doing `print(modis_YrMo.getInfo()[1])` I obtain: `{'type': 'Image', 'bands': [{'id': 'NDVI', 'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'float', 'min': -1, 'max': 1}, 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'crs_transform': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}], 'properties': {'month': 3, 'year': 2001}}`

So, when I try to reduce to the mean inside each polygon with `calcmean()`  I get the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_7150/1879499974.py", line 10, in <cell line: 10>
    finalNDVI_1000 = modis_YrMo.map(calcmean(pts1000))

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/apifunction.py", line 205, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: func.call(*args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=unnecessary-lambda

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/function.py", line 67, in call
    return self.apply(self.nameArgs(args, kwargs))

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/function.py", line 80, in apply
    result = computedobject.ComputedObject(self, self.promoteArgs(named_args))

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/function.py", line 107, in promoteArgs
    promoted_args[name] = Function._promoter(args[name], spec['type'])

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/__init__.py", line 252, in _Promote
    return CustomFunction.create(arg, 'Object', ['Object'] * args_count)

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/customfunction.py", line 125, in create
    return CustomFunction(signature, func)

  File "/home/lbianchi/.conda/envs/ee/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/customfunction.py", line 43, in __init__
    if body(*variables) is None:

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_7150/1879499974.py", line 3, in regionmean
    reduced = image.reduceRegions(

AttributeError: 'ComputedObject' object has no attribute 'reduceRegions'
```

But I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with the solution, inspired by the answer to [Get results in an Earth Engine python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633088/get-results-in-an-earth-engine-python-script) and using the [ee_to_pandas()](https://geemap.org/common/#geemap.common.ee_to_pandas) function of the `geemap` package.

I used `ee.ImageCollection()` to transform the list I obtained after reducing the initial MODIS collection to monthly-year means.

Then, `flatten()` this collection, so it's not nested collections. This returns a FeatureCollection.

And finally, convert this FeatureCollection to a DataFrame using `geemap.ee_to_pandas()`:

```py
finalNDVI_1000 = ee.ImageCollection(modis_YrMo).map(calcmean(pts1000)).flatten()
df = geemap.ee_to_pandas(finalNDVI_1000)
```